# Get all <li> elements from inside a certain <div> with C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I have a web page consisting of several `<div>` elements.

I would like to write a program that prints all the li elements inside a `<div>` after a certain `<h4>` header. Could anyone give me some help or sample code?

```html
<div id="content">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href...></a> THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div "content">` makes no sense. `<div id="content">` would however.

Comment: typo. should be <div id="content">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it come to parsing HTML in C#, don't try to write your own.  The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is almost certainly capable of doing what you want!

What parts are constant:

1. The 'id' in the DIV?
2. The h4

Searching a complete HTML document and reacting on H4 alone is likely to be a mess, whereas if you know the DIV has the ID of "content" then just look for that!

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

if ( doc.DocumentNode != null )
{
   var divs = doc.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//div")
                 .Where(e => e.Descendants().Any(e => e.Name == "h4"));

   // You now have all of the divs with an 'h4' inside of it.

   // The rest of the element structure, if constant needs to be examined to get
   // the rest of the content you're after.
}
```

Comment: I have the html agility pack but could you please give me some sample code to do what I need because my previous attempts failed. Pretty new to html parsing and coding in general.

Comment: Show us your previous attempts and I'm sure someone will be able to point out where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If its a web page why would you need to do HTML Parsing. Would not the technology that you are using to build the web page would give access to all the element of the page. For example if you are using ASP.NET, you could assign id's to your UL and LI(with runat server tag) and they would be available in code behind ?

Could you explain your scenario what you are trying to do ? If you trying to make a web request, download the html as string, then scrapping the HTML would make sense

**EDIT**
Think this should work

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(myHtmlFile);

    foreach (HtmlNode p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
    {
        if(p.Attributes["id"].Value == "content")
        {
            foreach(HtmlNode child in p.ChildNodes.SelectNodes("//ul"))
            {
                if(p.PreviousSibling.InnerText() == "Header")
                {
                    foreach(HtmlNode liNodes in p.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        //liNodes represent all childNode
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the source from a website using the WebClient and then I need to parse on the specific thing I need but I don't really know how to use the HTML Agility Pack properly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I get the following error: 
Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain     a definition for 'attribute' and no extension method 'attribute' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the stuff that's between all `<li></li>` tags underneath the `<div id="content">` tag and comes right after a `<h4>` tag, then this should suffice:

```
//Load your document first.
//Load() accepts a Stream, a TextReader, or a string path to the file on your computer
//If the entire document is loaded into a string, then use .LoadHtml() instead.
HtmlDocument mainDoc = new HtmlDocument();
mainDoc.Load("c:\foobar.html");


//Select all the <li> nodes that are inside of an element with the id of "content"
// and come directly after an <h4> tag.
HtmlNodeCollection processMe = mainDoc.GetElementbyId("content")
                                      .SelectNodes("//h4/following-sibling::*[1]//li");

//Iterate through each <li> node and print the inner text to the console
foreach (HtmlNode listElement in processMe)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listElement.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: I get an error on the .load function. Using following code maindoc.load(webclient.downloadstring(URL)). Does the load work with input as a string?

Comment: You would have to use `.LoadHtml()` instead of `.Load()` to parse a string. Using a string in `.Load()` tells it which file to open on your computer, like "c:\mywebpage.html".

Comment: Let me edit my answer a little to explain that and to adjust the XPath string in `SelectNodes()`.

Comment: and who did you build up this string: //h4/following-sibling::*[1]//li
I am getting closer still not what I really need but I am learning much. Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: You can find out most of what you might need from the [MSDN XPath Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471 "MSDN XPath Syntax") article. What `//h4/following-sibling::*[1]//li` is saying is, "//h4" : take an <h4> element , "/following-sibling::*[1]" : take the first sibling following that <h4> element (which would be <ul> in your example) , "//li" : take an <li> element anywhere under the previous element. I know it's confusing, but that's about the simplest I can explain it without going into way too much detail :)

Comment: oke thanks I understand it a bit better now. Will mess around a bit and see what comes out. Thanks all for the help. Will keep posted on progress

Comment: No problems! If you need a little more help, just edit your question to include a couple more specifics, like what you're current output is and what output you're expecting to get.